# How to prevent System.Data.SQLite ADO.NET provider opening a new file handle every access to database?

Tags: c#, sqlite, linq-to-sql

I'm accessing a small SQLite database in C# using [LINQ to SQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/linq/) and [System.Data.SQLite](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Data.SQLite/).

Here is typical code I use to read data from DB :

```
var context = new MyDataContext();
var foo = context.GetTable<Foo>().Single(x => x.Id == ...);
```

MyDataContext.cs :

```
public class MyDataContext : DataContext
{
    public MyDataContext() :
        base(new SQLiteConnection(@"Data Source=somefile.db"))
    {
    }
}
```

I have been tempted to put DataContext into an using statement (since it is IDisposable) or to use a singleton but almost all examples I found (include in books) create a new DataContext for each use. Here is what [Microsoft says](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.linq.datacontext?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#remarks) about it :

> In general, a DataContext instance is designed to last for one "unit of work" however your application defines that term. A DataContext is lightweight and is not expensive to create. A typical LINQ to SQL application creates DataContext instances at method scope or as a member of short-lived classes that represent a logical set of related database operations.

I have been wondering when the SQLite database file is open/closed behind the scenes. I was expecting some sort of pool maintained (like for SQLConnection). Results are surprising.

If I run this :

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < 500 ; i++)
{
    using(var context = new MyDataContext())
    {
        var foo = context.GetTable<Foo>().ToList();
    }
}
```

It seems SQLite db file is opened many times but never closed. In fact, at the exact moment I stop the application, I got 500 lines like this in [Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) :

[image]

Ouch.

I have tried to improve it by writing this:

```
using (var context = new MyDataContext())
{
    for (int i = 0 ; i < 500 ; i++)
    {
        var foo = context.GetTable<Foo>().ToList();
    }
}
```

It is just the same (500 CloseFile calls). It seems the file opening is done at the exact moment `GetTable<T>().ToList()` is called, not when DataContext is instantiated as I thought.

It is of course not acceptable. Am I doing something wrong or is this a limitation of System.Data.SQLite ? How can I improve it ? I would like file to be closed right after usage or at least reduce number of file handles opened during application life cycle.

Comment: Not exactly sure what you are asking as _wanting the file to be be closed right after usage_ sounds like it conflicts with the desire to prevent  _tons of file handles opened_ , but does pooling help? (See https://www.connectionstrings.com/sqlite-net-provider/with-connection-pooling/ for example). I guess this depends on the linq provider, but I don't see this multiple open/close behaviour in LinqPad which use the IQ Toolkit which enables pooling.

Comment: It seems `Pooling=true` does the trick. I got only one `CloseFile` call after process is shutdown, not matter how much read of write to DB there was.